# Javascript code update include count total for each record

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to modify some code in which I need to add a count to an array.

Here is the data and code:

```
var data = {
  "people": [{
      "id": "32",
      "description": "some description",
      "archived": "",
      "new": 0,
      "names": [{
        "name": "name 1",
        "translations": null
      }, {
        "name": "name 2",
        "translations": null
      }],
    }, {
      "id": "56",
      "description": "some description",
      "archived": "",
      "new": 0,
      "names": [{
        "name": "name 3",
        "translations": null
      }, {
        "name": "name 4",
        "translations": null
      }],
    }, {
      "id": "99",
      "description": "some description",
      "archived": "",
      "new": 0,
      "names": null,
    },

  ]
};

var mainData = [data];
var namesList = [];

for (var i = 0; i < mainData[0].people.length; i++) {

  var obj = mainData[0].people[i];

  if( obj.names ) {

   var nme = obj.names.map( function(item){
    return item.name; 
   });
   namesList = namesList.concat(nme);

}

}

console.log(namesList); //This should have the list of names
```

What I need to do is to add a new array which contains to count of each name field for example..the current's data output would be:

**[2, 2]** ... because there are 2 records which contain 2 names in each.

How can I add this?

Comment: try `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: i think the json is not frmatted properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the length of your `nme` array to some other array that you want to hold your counts

```
var namesCount = [];
//...
if (obj.names) {
   var nme = obj.names.map(function(item) {
     return item.name;
   });
   namesList = namesList.concat(nme);
   namesCount.push(nme.length);
}
//..
console.log(namesCount);
```

Demo

```js
var data = {
  "people": [{
      "id": "32",
      "description": "some description",
      "archived": "",
      "new": 0,
      "names": [{
        "name": "name 1",
        "translations": null
      }, {
        "name": "name 2",
        "translations": null
      }],
    }, {
      "id": "56",
      "description": "some description",
      "archived": "",
      "new": 0,
      "names": [{
        "name": "name 3",
        "translations": null
      }, {
        "name": "name 4",
        "translations": null
      }],
    }, {
      "id": "99",
      "description": "some description",
      "archived": "",
      "new": 0,
      "names": null,
    },

  ]
};

var namesList = [];
var namesCount = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.people.length; i++) {

  var obj = data.people[i];

  if (obj.names) {
    var nme = obj.names.map(function(item) {
      return item.name;
    });
    namesList = namesList.concat(nme);
    namesCount.push(nme.length);
  }
}
console.log(namesCount);
```

If you want to store it on your original `data` then just set it as some property

```
data.namesCount = [];
//...
if (obj.names) {
   var nme = obj.names.map(function(item) {
     return item.name;
   });
   namesList = namesList.concat(nme);
   data.namesCount.push(nme.length);
}
//..
console.log(data.namesCount);
```

Also since you are not filtering out or removing any objects from `obj.names` you could just get the length of that array to get a count

```
namesCount.push( obj.names.length );
```